# Javascripts not precompiled?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

in my `app/assets/javascripts/specific.js` I have

```
//= require_tree ./specific
```

in `app/assets/javascripts/specific/chat` I have `pusher.js`

Also, in `config/environments/production` I have

`config.assets.precompile += %w( specific.js some_other_manifest.js )`

However, when I go into production (on heroku) it still complains `pusher.js` is not precompiled. What am I doing wrong here?

While the application is deployed, the javascript files seem to be compiled.

from Heroku logs:

```
   Compiled specific/chat/pusher.js  (0ms)  (pid 1042)
   Compiled specific.js  (60ms)  (pid 1042)
```

But when I go to the view,

```
 ActionView::Template::Error (specific/chat/pusher.js isn't precompiled):
     1: <%= javascript_include_tag 'specific/chat/pusher' %>
     2: <%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %>
     3: 
     4: <div id="chat-header">
   app/views/messages/index.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_messages_index_html_erb___3285714722884343394_70246542189040'
```

I also tried putting `config.assets.precompile ..` option inside `config/application.rb` instead of `production.rb`

**Related:** [Assets say "not precompiled" when they are precompiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640808/assets-say-not-precompiled-when-they-are-precompiled)

When I run `assets:precompile` and look in `public/assets` folder, I see that they are all precompiled (e.g. `specific-bfgbfbf4534535.js`)

**So the asset is actually precompiled, but the error says it isn't precompiled**

From my view:

`<%= javascript_include_tag 'specific/chat/pusher.js' %>`

Comment: I've never used Heroku so I don't know if there's something Heroku-specific going on here. In your application.html.erb, do you have a line `javascript_include_tag 'specific.js'`?

Comment: It's not supposed to be included in application.html.erb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't include specific files, you include the entire manifest, that's the whole point of manifests.

This can't work:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'specific/chat/pusher' %>
```

Instead, you need a single include for the top-level manifest:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'specifics' %>
```

From your comment below your question:

> It's not supposed to be included in application.html.erb

That isn't how precompiled assets work. You need to include `specifics.js`, or build another (more granular) manifest. The point of manifests is that they produce a single minified blob of code to be included. You specifically say you see a `specific-bfgbfbf4534535.js` in your compiled assets folder; *that* is the file that will be included, and it contains `pusher.js`.

Comment: WOW. Your answer clarified the last bit that I was missing to understand. Then when I do `javascript_include_tag params[:controller]`, does the app actually load the specific part contained within `application.js` instead of looking at `some_controller.js.coffee` ?

Comment: Err, no. You should never do `javascript_include_tag params[:controller]`, unless you've set up manifests for each controller. It definitely doesn't load any specific *part* of `application.js`; it loads **all** of `application.js`, every time. It's up to you to code your JavaScript so that this works, and your scripts don't clobber each other.

Comment: That sounds more logical. Then what's the purpose of keeping all the automatically-generated js.coffee files that relate to each controller?

Comment: @MaximusS You don't *have* to keep them, it's just meant to be an organizational aide.

Answer (score 0):

try to precompile all assets:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( *.css *.js )
```

Comment: Thanks for your input Eru, but this does not solve the problem. (I tried this to solve other issues before)